# Django Read png image from url then pass it to HttpResponse

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to to read png image from private url then write it to HttpResponse.
I have this view that will get a layer from geoServer as a png image then open it and read it then return it as HttpResponse:

```
def get_layer(request):
   #this url will return png image
   url='https://example.com/geoserver/layer/wms?.......' 
   r = requests.get(url)
   with open(r, "rb") as fp:
       img = Image.open(fp)
   return HttpResponse(img)
```

I am getting an error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: invalid file: Response [200]

/main/views.py in test1
    with open(r, "rb") as fp: ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
r           <Response [200]>
request     <WSGIRequest: GET '/test/'>
url         'https://example.com/geoserver/layer/wms?.......'
```

All want I want is get the png file from the url then pass it the the HttpResponse so when one call my view, he/she will get the image only with my Django path. I do not want to save the image locally I just want to assign it to a variable and pass it. 
I am using:  Django 1.11, python3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
def get_layer(request):
   #this url will return png image
   url='https://example.com/geoserver/layer/wms?.......' 
   r = requests.get(url)
   return HttpResponse(r.content, content_type="image/png")
```

Comment: @Anatol believe this should work for any type of image yep, when content_type is supplied correctly